# Who won the game?

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, parsing, tic-tac-toe

### Task

Everyone knows the game "Tic-Tac-Toe". Your task is it, to evaluate an ascii tic-tac-toe matchfield. Your Programm/Function should output/return the winner: O, X or nobody (N).

### Pattern

```
X|O|X
O|X|O
O|O|X
```

In this case your programm/function should output/return 'X'

### Rules

- Input can come from STDIN, function arguments, command line argument, file, whatever suits you.
- The program can be a function, full program, whatever works, really, as long as no external files are needed to run it.
- You can assume that the input is valid.

### Test Cases

```
X|O|X
O|X|X  = O
O|O|O

O|X|O
X|X|O  = X
O|X|X

X|O|X
O|X|O  = N
O|X|O
```

This is [code-colf](/questions/tagged/code-colf), so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

Comment: The first test case... A GLIDER?

Comment: @SIGSEGV Good eye!